# Why are arithmetical operations on during row reduction counted in this way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity

I am reading the section on counting arithmetic operations in Strang's book. It says:

> [The] operations are of two kinds. We divide by the pivot to find out what multiple (say $\ell$) of the pivot is to be subtracted. When we do this subtraction, we continually meet a "multiply-subtract" combination; ...
>
> [In the end he gets the value $\dfrac {n^3-n}{3}$ for the number of operations required to reduce the whole matrix.]

My question is, why we call "multiplication-subtraction" one operation, when it is in fact two. Is it because in general, a "multiplication-subtraction" takes the same ammount of time for a computer to do as a "division"?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a single change affecting a single row. Maybe that's what it's about?

Comment: @Arthur Hmm maybe.

Comment: Using jupyter notebooks in python, you can use the cell magic phrase `%%timeit` to find how long a particular block of code takes to run.  The blocks `x = 5 + 3` and `x = 5 * 3 - 2` each averaged 9.07 nano seconds over 100 million trials when I performed the test.  This implies to me that the much more costly operation timewise is the action of storing the value into memory rather than the actual arithmetic occurring.  Replacing the values with six digit numbers doesn't impact the performance, nor does increasing the number of arithmetic operations.  Adding an additional assignment does.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hmm interesting. I wonder why this "counting of operations" thing is a thing then. I'm pretty sure I've seen the $\dfrac {n^3-n}{3}$ figure in multiple places.